# Tilemap displaying incorrectly on iOS using Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, tiled

I used Tiled to create a tilemap to use in one of my games for iOS; however, it displays incorrectly when I run it. I've tried making multiple different .tmx files with different file sizes for phone, phonehd, tablet, and tablethd. The tilemap is base64 zlib compressed, but I've also tried no compression and gzip compressed. I've included the code used to display it.

```
self.tileMap = [CCTiledMap tiledMapWithFile:@"assets/Test.tmx"];
[self addChild:_tileMap z:-1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that instead of using a tileset, I was using a collection of images as a tileset in Tiled. Apparently that causes weird results with the tilemap in Cocos2D. It worked fine after using a sprite sheet.